# GCC compiler warning flag for zero variadic macro arguments

Tags: c++, gcc

What is the compiler warning flag for zero variadic macro arguments in GCC (I am using GCC 5.3.0)?

The warning is triggered by code like this

```
// for illustration purposes only:
int foo(int i) { return 0; };
#define FOO(A, ...) foo(A, ##__VA_ARGS__)
FOO(1);
      ^  warning: ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro
```

but the warning doesn't indicate which flag is used to enable/disable the warning (this is typically shown in square brackets `[-Wwarning-flag-name]`).

In clang it is `-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments`. I haven't been able to find anything like that in the [warning documentation of gcc-5.3.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

I've tried `-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments`, `-Wvarargs`, `-Wno-variadic-macros` (thanks to @ Revolver_Ocelot) but none of these is in charge of this warning.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It doesn't look like `foo(int i)` has been defined in a way that makes it compatible with variadic macros.

Comment: @Xirema I am trying to disable a warning, the example is for illustration purposes.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments) might help out. You could "overload" the macro with different number of variables so that the macro with one parameter works.

Comment: @callyalater That's pretty wrong. I actually just want to pass the compiler the `-Wno-warning-flag-name` and be done with it. Its a warning, it must have a flag. Another option is to use `push`/`pop` locally but you still need the warning flag name.

Comment: Does `-Wno-variadic-macros` helps?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot nope, that flag doesn't remove this warning. I've added to the list of tried one in the question (with attribution). In the webpage it say that that flag is for warning on variadic macros in older versions of C (C90).

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16767901/620382

Comment: @Zulan the first answer there provides the warning flag for clang, but not for GCC (where it shows the GCC warning, the warning flag is missing, and without that you cannot use it to disable the warning).

Comment: And what about `FOO(1,);`?

Comment: @Zulan I want to disable the warning not work around it :D 
Basically the only answer for this question is the flag that enables/disables this particular warning in GCC.

Comment: What flag is used to specify standard? Omitting variadic arguments is illegal and it should be an error. There are gnu extensions which prevent it. Try to use `std=gnu++11`. It might be that compiling with strict adherence to standard gives you this message.

Comment: I've rephrased the question to make it clear that i am just looking for the name of the warning flag.

Comment: From what I can see it looks like this warning is only surfaced when compiling with `-pedantic`.  If not using that there is no warning(on my machine).  I am not sure if you can surpress the warnings that come form using `-pedantic`

Comment: `Omitting variadic arguments is illegal and it should be an error`. No, omitting variadic arguments requires a diagnostic but it is not an error (the standard just require compilers to emit a diagnostic to be standard conformant).  All compilers (IBM, Cray, Intel, MSVC, gcc, clang, nvcc...) expand `FOO(1)` to `foo(1)`, none of them expands it to `foo(1,)`, but to be standard compliant they need to tell you about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver i've tried `#pragma GCC diagnostic push`, `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"`, ..., without luck :/

Comment: Yes but since a diagnostic is required I doubt they want it suppressed since it is `-pedantic`.

Comment: @NathanOliver compiling without `-Wpedantic` removes the warning. Now I need to find a way to remove this warning in a couple of lines instead of in my whole program :/

Comment: @gnzlbg Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304255/partially-disable-pedantic-warnings-in-gcc-within-source

Comment: @NathanOliver the problem there is that for disabling pedantic you have to write `__extension__` before the expression that causes the warning, and this warning is only issued when the expression is omitted...

Comment: @gnzlbg Write what up as an answer?  do not use `-Wpedantic` and the warning will go away?

Comment: I've posted a new question, now that this one is answered and we know the name of the warning flag (-Wpedantic) to figure out how to disable it for a macro definition within a source file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587137/how-to-suppress-gcc-variadic-macro-argument-warning-for-zero-arguments-for-a-par

Comment: @NathanOliver that the name of the warning flag to enable disable this warning is `-Wpedantic` basically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning flag that is causing the issue is `-Wpedantic`.  This is because omitting variadic arguments is illegal and it requires a diagnostic.  A warning satisfies that requirement.

Comment: I don't get the sense of this warning :  `warning: ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro` Isn't the `##` before `__VA_ARGS__` supposed to delete the comma if it isn't used ? That doesn't make any the -pedantic flag output this. Good thing the warning disappeared in the next versions of g++.