# How to suppress GCC variadic macro argument warning for zero arguments for a particular macro definition within a source file

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

I want to suppress GCC variadic macro argument warning for zero arguments, produced for example by:

```
// for illustration purposes only:
int foo(int i) { return 0; };
#define FOO(A, ...) foo(A, ##__VA_ARGS__)
FOO(1);
     ^  warning: ISO C++11 requires at least one argument for the "..." in a variadic macro
```

for a particular macro definition within a source file when using GCC 5.3.0.

In clang this is done as follows:

```
// ... large file
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments"
#define FOO(A, ...) foo(A, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
// ... large file

// not necessary on the same file
FOO(1);  // doesnt trigger the warning
```

In gcc it looks like `-pedantic` is a magical kind of warning type so the following just doesn't work:

```
// ... large file
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
#define FOO(A, ...) foo(A, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
// ... large file
```

Just to be clear, the warning should be enabled in the whole program except in this particular snippet of code. This is about fine grained control. Disabling the warning in GCC for the whole program can be achieved by just not passing `-pedantic` to the compiler.

Comment: @Zulan that question asks for the name of the warning flag that enables disables this warning. This question asks for how exactly use that warning flag to disable this warning in a macro definition within a source file (your answer fits better here).

Comment: I would suggest to just edit the original question to clarify your intent.

Comment: I could do that but then basically don't make much sense to me anymore (feels like changing the question too much). For somebody interested in turning of the warning for the whole program just knowing the flag is enough. This one is a bit... more about fine grained control since `-Wpedantic` looks more magical than other warnings in GCC (but not in clang).

Comment: I'm going with your argument and moving my answer here.

Comment: An alternative solution for the case presented would be `#define FOO(...) foo(__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to suppress this using

`#pragma GCC system_header`

But that applies for the rest of the file, and you cannot only use it in included files. So doesn't provide perfect scoping and may require some reshuffling / indirect inclusion of header files.

(But quite frankly, if you can't *fix* the header file to be standards-conforming, you might as well consider the whole header a system_header, which excludes it from producing most warnings.)

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wvariadic-macros"
#define FOO(A, ...) foo(A, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Do you have links to any resources related to this functionality?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: Doesn't work for GCC but works for Clang O.o